# Combobox Requery datasheet view after combobox addition

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a subform datasheet view on a main form and it's client field is a combobox from a list of clients. I also have a add new client button above this datasheet view. When I person is not in the client table, the user uses the popup button to add a new client. When the user goes back into the datasheet, it does not requery.

I have tried:

```
On enter: Code Form.requery
On click. clientid datasheet, clientid.requery
on after update: clientid.requery
```

but none of it works. What is the best way to do a query after the combobox has been edited?

Comment: It is not clear where your combobox is. This links may help: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm -- You need to requery the combobox itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to Requery the sub form control is as follows:

```
Me.SubFormName.Requery
```

The code to Requery a ComboBox would be as follows:

```
Me.ComboBoxName.Requery
```